# How to remove file extension from Mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

**I want to make pretty url out of:**

```
 http://www.example.com/search-destroy?id=nameOfCharacter
```

**I have this mod_rewrite:**

```
 RewriteRule ^search-destroy/([^/]*)$ /search-destroy?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**That generates this urL:**

```
 http://www.example.com/search-destroy/nameOfCharacter.php
```

I want to leave out the .php extension here, how would the mod_rewrite look?

Comment: May be this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Comment: No relly, have been reading most of the posts.

Comment: Does the url work without .php?

Comment: url does not work without .php thats the case.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar situation, i have done something as shown below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On  
        RewriteRule ^search_destroy/([^/.]+)?$ your_php.php?search_destroy=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

There is some changes.

1) one common php script - "your_php.php"

and in your_php.php - you should handle it as shown below

```
if(isset($_GET['search_destroy'])) {
   // YOUR CODE BASED ON YOUR DYNAMIC id
```

}

Hope this helps you

Thanks